# Error Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 in Sample VR iOS App

Tags: ios, google-cardboard, google-vr

I'm trying to play around with the sample iOS app on the Google VR SDK but I'm running into problems after cloning and installing. I've added and installed CocoaPods.

The error I receive after running the Treasurehunt.xcworkspace file is:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GVRAudioEngine", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TreasureHuntRenderer.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GVRCardboardView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TreasureHuntViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I predicted that it would be the .m files not being compiled properly, but the TreasureHunt .m files seem to all be there. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried running the app on a device? The x86_64 architecture is for the simulator and there is a chance their library may only not have support for running in the simulator so it wouldn't be compiled for that.

Comment: @zfetters I receive the following error when I try and run it on my device: An App ID with Identifier 'com.test.TreasureHunt' is not available. Please enter a different string.

Comment: if you are going to use an existing app id you will need to use the wildcard provisioning profile from your dev account. You should be able to see it in your list of provisioning profiles on the dev portal. If you need some extra info about getting that stuff setup i would recommend the following link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Google inconveniently changed the name of the pod from "GVRSDK" to "CardboardSDK". So try adding the line `pod 'CardboardSDK'` to your Podfile. Then run `pod update` while you're in your project folder in the terminal. In each of your TreasureHunt.m files, replace every instance of "GVR" with "GCS". This should direct it to the CardboardSDK instead.

Answer (score 0):

the problem can be probably enabled bitcode, I had same issues when I try to run on physical device - try in Project preferencies under Build Settings search for Bitcode and set value to NO.

this helps if GVRSDK is working on simulator and not on physical device.